# Given an integrable function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ , $\int f(x)$ is a function.

Tags: calculus, integration

**Given an integrable function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R  $ , $\int f(x)$ is a function.**

I have to prove or disprove this statement.

I am quite confused I do not know how to proceed . If there was limit on the integral , I could have said
$\int f(x)$ is a continuous function.Can anyone tell me what will happen in this case?

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question; maybe you meant $g(x)=\int_a^x f(t) dt$... And there must be some hypothesis on $f$ (at least it should be Riemann-integrable)

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Since $\int f(x)dx$ is only defined up to a constant it is not a function.

Comment: What is your exact definition of $\int f(x)$?

Comment: I got my answer.@KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: $f(x) = \int \sin x = -\cos x + C , C \in \mathbb R$. That is why for a praticular $x$ there will be infinite $f(x)$. @MartinR

Answer (score 0):

In book Robert Creighton Buck, Ellen F. Buck - Advanced Calculus(1978) page 181 you can find following definition:

Definition 4: A function $F$ is an antiderivative (or primitive or indefinite
integral) of $f$ on an interval $I$ if $F'(x) = f(x)$for all $x \in I$.

Same on Vladimir A. Zorich - Mathematical Analysis I-(2016) pages 306-307, same on [antiderivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative).

Accordingly these definitions indefinite integral is **of course function**.

Simple analysis gives, that if exists one such $F$, then $F+C$, for any constant $C$, also satisfies definition, so this definition does not define unique function for given $f$, but rather the any member of set of functions $\{F+C: F'=f\}$. So if we want to have definition of unique object, then it's more appropriate to introduce definition based on mentioned set.